# Error while deploying NextJS app to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel, next-auth

Hi guys I am trying to deploy NEXT-JS App to Vercel but it keeps giving the error below annoyingly even I have app and pages folders under my project root. I tried to find the solution on google but I couldn't find the same as mine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdmv6.png)

here is my folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNEoS.png)

Comment: Honestly sounds like a configuration issue, the image you provided looks correct. Are you sure the code you are pushing to git has the same root? Have you changed any of hte default Vercel Next build settings?

Comment: Hi Chris!  no I didn't change it. build root directory in Vercel './' stays default. Here is my github link https://github.com/ErkinN/Airbnb-clone.git

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you don't have appDir disabled in your next.config.js.

No:

```json
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: false,
  }
}
```

Expected:

```json
const nextConfig = {
}
```

Secondly, make sure nothing comes after your `npm run build` command, without the use of `&&`

No:

```bash
"build": "next build prisma generate"
```

Expected:

```bash
"build": "next build && prisma generate"
```

Without the `&&` next will try to use prisma as a directory root.

Comment: Should I change it to 'true' ? I changed it to 'true' but still it gives the same error

Comment: @ERKIN I checked out the code in more detail. The answer was related to missing && in your build command. You have other errors, but they would be for a new question/answer